# Formatting a Grid View for an Oracle APEX Application

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

When I first started to develop the APEX application I am working on my database was one table structured like this:

```
|Row Header|Criteria 1|Criteria 2| Criteria 3 | Criteria 4 |Criteria 5 |
| Category | Type A   | Type B   | Type B     | Type A     | Type A    |
| ID       | 2.3      | 2.4      | 2.5        | 3.1        | 3.2       |
| Part A   | Yes      | Yes      | Yes        | No         | Yes       |
| Part B   | Yes      | No       | Yes        | Yes        | Yes       |
| Part C   | No       | Yes      | Yes        | Yes        | No        |
```

I was very new to Oracle and databases then, so I modeled it after a spreadsheet.  The purpose is to track if a part meets the necessary criteria.  Once the part does meet the criteria a 'yes' is put in the intersecting cell between the part and the criteria.  Some additional info is stored in the table, such as criteria ID and category.

After doing some research I realized that it would be best to split them up into three tables structured like this:

**CRITERIA TABLE:**

```
| Criteria   | Category | ID   |
| Criteria 1 | Type A   | 2.3  |
| Criteria 2 | Type A   | 2.4  |
| Criteria 3 | Type B   | 2.5  |
```

This table stores all the additional information regarding the criteria.

**PARTS TABLE:**

```
| Part   | Part ID |
| Part 1 | blah    |
| Part 2 | blah    |
| Part 3 | blah    |
```

Same thing as the criteria table, but for parts instead.

**BRIDGE TABLE:**

```
| Criteria   | Part   |
| Criteria 1 | Part 1 |
| Criteria 2 | Part 2 |
| Criteria 3 | Part 3 |
```

This table holds all the "yes" responses.  If a criterion and part share a row it means that the part in question meets the criterion in question.  Any part and criterion combination that isn't present in the bridge table would not yet meet the criterion.

I'm going into detail on this because the users of the application I am working on need a "grid view" in oracle APEX that has criteria on the y-axis and parts on the x-axis of a table.  The users would also like to be able to edit the data from this "grid view" the same way you would edit data on a spreadsheet but if this isn't a good idea I can live without it as long as you can view it in the way I outlined.

**REQUESTED GRID VIEW:**

```
| Row Header | Part 1 | Part 2 | Part 3 | Part 4 | Part 5 |
| Criteria 1 | No     | No     | Yes    | Yes    | No     |
| Criteria 3 | Yes    | No     | No     | Yes    | No     |
| Criteria 4 | Yes    | Yes    | Yes    | No     | Yes    |
| Criteria 5 | Yes    | No     | Yes    | Yes    | Yes    |
| Criteria 6 | No     | Yes    | Yes    | Yes    | No     |
```

Based on the current data structure that I have, I'm encountering a great deal of trouble accomplishing this and I would really like to keep this structure if at all possible because many other aspects of the app rely on it.

A few other things to note are that parts are created somewhat frequently, and the names of the Parts and Criteria that I used in the tables are placeholders.  This fact has strayed me away from creating a table where the table's columns correspond to a part since this would mean adding and modifying columns rather frequently.

Any help would be very much appreciated and I'll be monitoring this post the best I can to answer any questions anyone might have.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex requirement. Here is how I would approach this, but there are probably other (and better) solutions possible. Here is the high-level break out into pieces.

The data structure you suggest is correct: 2 tables and an intersect table with matching records

- Use a classic report or an interactive report. Interactive grid doesn't support a dynamic number of columns
- Generate the query in a multi-step process. First calculate the number of columns you'll have and use that process to set the column headers (each column header would be a page item), then generate the dynamic query with that number of columns for the specific criteria. Use a datasource of type "function returning query"
- use  a dynamic action on click of a jquery selector in each cell of the report. Use javascript data attribute to define which cell (a data attribute for the the criteria and one for the part.

Note that this is not a simple project. It requires a lot of customization and it will be a lot of work. It'd be easier if it was not a grid.

Comment: Would it be easier to accomplish if the Criteria were the column headers and the parts were in rows?  This way the number of columns would be static.

Comment: If the nr of criteria is static then that would indeed be easier. You could generate create a view (or just a query) that generates all the rows, represent those in an interactive grid (maybe with checkboxes ?) and use custom dml instead of the default ig process to handle the rows. You can't use the standard ig process because each row in the report corresponds to many rows in the db.